# Exception The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value. when trying to get a DataSet from an XML string via ReadXML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML string which is output from a Visual Fox Pro based COM object that I am trying to read into a DataSet. When I do this it throws an exception "The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value."

Based on googling and Stack Overflow searches this is normally a problem with a date format. I do have a field "Changed" of type datetime but I do not have any records in the XML with any data in this field. Assuming that field is causing the problem, and that I never need data from that field, how can I tell it to ignore data in that field or to treat it as a string or something.

Here's the offending XML:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<VFPData>
    <xsd:schema id="VFPData" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xsd:element name="VFPData" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="v_issue2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="issue2id" type="xsd:int"/>
                                <xsd:element name="issueid" type="xsd:int"/>
                                <xsd:element name="materielid" type="xsd:int"/>
                                <xsd:element name="nsn">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:maxLength value="14"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="nomen">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:maxLength value="35"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="qty" type="xsd:int"/>
                                <xsd:element name="serialized" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                                <xsd:element name="sewn" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                                <xsd:element name="tamid" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xsd:element name="qty_return" type="xsd:int"/>
                                <xsd:element name="qty_lost" type="xsd:int"/>
                                <xsd:element name="qty_bo" type="xsd:int"/>
                                <xsd:element name="matlocid" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xsd:element name="changed" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
                                <xsd:element name="need_ldy" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xsd:element name="lotcontrol">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="location" minOccurs="0">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:maxLength value="13"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="backordid" type="xsd:int"/>
                                <xsd:element name="accessories" minOccurs="0">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:maxLength value="2147483647"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:choice>
                <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" processContents="lax"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571504</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>5238</materielid>
        <nsn>8405015299330</nsn>
        <nomen>DESERT 8 POINT XXS</nomen>
        <qty>2</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>true</sewn>
        <tamid>120</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol>N</lotcontrol>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571492</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>7483</materielid>
        <nsn>132510KIT4000</nsn>
        <nomen>BELT KIT</nomen>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571493</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>6415</materielid>
        <nsn>8420011121473</nsn>
        <nomen>T-SHIRTS, BROWN  COTTON XS</nomen>
        <qty>9</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571494</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>524</materielid>
        <nsn>8415012279547</nsn>
        <nomen>POLY PRO UNDERSHIRT,  XS</nomen>
        <qty>2</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571495</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>530</materielid>
        <nsn>8415012279543</nsn>
        <nomen>POLY PRO DRAWER, SM</nomen>
        <qty>2</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571496</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>7244</materielid>
        <nsn>8415015394045</nsn>
        <nomen>GORTEX FLEECE LINER XS/R</nomen>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571497</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>6422</materielid>
        <nsn>8430014939165</nsn>
        <nomen>BOOTS, HW STEEL TOE, DESERT 3N</nomen>
        <qty>2</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571498</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>5301</materielid>
        <nsn>8440015083357</nsn>
        <nomen>SOCKS, MOIST MGT XS</nomen>
        <qty>9</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571499</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>5461</materielid>
        <nsn>8415014753633</nsn>
        <nomen>DESERT CW TROUSERS XS XS</nomen>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571500</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>5445</materielid>
        <nsn>8415014702065</nsn>
        <nomen>DESERT CW PARKA  XS XS</nomen>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571501</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>5447</materielid>
        <nsn>8415013275324</nsn>
        <nomen>DCU DESERT TROUSER XS-XS</nomen>
        <qty>4</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571502</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>5285</materielid>
        <nsn>8415014863298</nsn>
        <nomen>DCU DESERT BLOUSE XS XXS</nomen>
        <qty>4</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
    <v_issue2>
        <issue2id>35571503</issue2id>
        <issueid>2772562</issueid>
        <materielid>5244</materielid>
        <nsn>8415013274828</nsn>
        <nomen>DCU DESERT SUN HAT 6-1/2</nomen>
        <qty>2</qty>
        <serialized>false</serialized>
        <sewn>false</sewn>
        <tamid>0</tamid>
        <qty_return>0</qty_return>
        <qty_lost>0</qty_lost>
        <qty_bo>0</qty_bo>
        <matlocid>0</matlocid>
        <changed/>
        <need_ldy>false</need_ldy>
        <lotcontrol/>
        <location/>
        <backordid>0</backordid>
        <accessories/>
    </v_issue2>
</VFPData>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work by using XMLReadMode.InferSchema and I assume it is now treating that element as some type other than a date.

```
MyDataSet.ReadXml(MyXMLStringReader, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
```